# Numbers on the push and pull button of SourceTree won't change

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I started using SourceTree few days ago and after I committed and pushed my changes to the remote GitHub repository, the numbers on the buttons remain the same, for example if the number on the push button becomes 3 when I committed a change, after I pushed it; it needs to be 0 or empty. But that's not the case here, it remains the same even though it has successfully been pushed. I also checked that my changes had been pushed using a web browser by going to the GitHub site. Is it because of the branch that I have pulled from and am pushing to are different or something else? Can any one please help cause I don't understand it... Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some other changes on other branches, waiting to be pushed ? Also another thing to try: Repository > Refresh Remote Status

Comment: Yea you're right, I was pushing to the branch but there were some changes to the master too so, since I needed to make changes to the branch only; it went away when I deleted the master branch from my local copy. Thanks for responding

Comment: You are welcome. Glad i helped :)

Comment: I found the numbers weren't correct sometimes :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same thing also happened to me too, I was working on branch I had push everting but was keeping appearing one unsend Push and miraculously also appear unsend Push on Master.
So what did was the same as Hristo Staykov and Sammie remove the Master branch from my local computer, since I had one miraculously unsend Push on Master did need to run this line terminal to remove the branch:

```
git branch -D master
```

And then Repository > Refresh Remote Status

Answer (score 4):

The numbers shown on the right hand side of the `Branches` panel reflect how many commits ahead or behind the [Tracking Branch](https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/understanding-tracking-branches-in-git) you currently are. If the numbers aren't what you expect, you should verify that the branch is tracking what you actually want.

You can verify the tracking branch by right clicking your local branch (as depicted below) and expanding the `Track remote branch` menu item. Finally, if you want to change the tracking branch simply click the new target from the list and Sourcetree will update accordingly. Hopefully that helps make sense of the disconnect that can happen when you rename branches and provides some details around why it happens and a simple way to resolve.

[image: tracking-branch-example]

Comment: I did what the above screenshot show, my branch which is not master, when I clicked on "Track remote branch" , it shows origin/master, I click on origin/mybranch, the number on push button disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I simply use the keyboard shortcut from the Repository menu:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (or <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> if you prefer)

My guess is that the shortcut would be the same or at least similar on Windows. Just look for the option called Refresh Remote Status under the Repository menu.

Comment: `SHIFT`+`ALT`+`R` on Windows client.